# orgmode sync beamer with header in orgmode file

Tags: org-mode, pdf-tools

I am creating my beamer presentations with orgmode and convert the file to tex and pdf when saving. This works quite fine.

What I am looking for is that the pdf (seen inside emacs with pdfview/pdf-tools) file syncs the slide number which is shown with the corresponding header I am having my cursor on.

Does someone have a hint how to achieve this?

I am using spacemacs-develop (but Ithink that this is not so relevant here).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The [org-noter](https://github.com/weirdNox/org-noter) package keeps your notes in sync with the PDF, so I'd start there.

You could also write a command that (1) moves the cursor to the next heading and (2) visits the PDF and skips to the next slide/page.

Comment: Thank you very much... sorry for the delayed reply. I am current thought is to count the header and jump to the slides. This could work with beamer as the levels correspond quite well to the slides pages, at least for handout version.